# Heroku "Something Went Wrong" when trying to create a new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am trying to make a form that will create a new 'room'.  However, when I push it to Heroku I am getting this error:  'We're sorry, but something went wrong.'  I am using rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1.1.  I am also using Heroku.

If it helps, I am kind of new to rails and am trying to port what I learned [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/) to my new 'rooms' type.

This is my view/model/controller:

**view:**  (app/views/rooms/index.html.erb)

```
<% if current_user %>
  <h1>Create Room</h1>
  <div class="Sign_Form">
    <%= form_for(:room, :url => {:controller => 'rooms', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
      <p> Created By:</br> <%= f.text_field :created_by%> </p>
      <p> Name:</br> <%= f.text_field :name%> </p>
      <p> Description:</br> <%= f.text_field :description%> </p>
      <%= f.submit :Createroom %>
    <% end %>
    <% if @room.errors.any? %>
      <ul class="Createroom_Errors">
        <% for message_error in @room.errors.full_messages %>
          <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <h1>All Rooms</h1>
  <% if @rooms.nil? %>
    Rooms is nil
  <% else %>
    <% @rooms.each do |room| %>
      <%= room.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'welcome' %>
<% end %>
```

**Model:** (app/model/room.rb)

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
  end
end
```

**Controller:** (app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb)

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @rooms = Room.all
  end

  def new
    @room = Room.new
  end

  def create
    @room = Room.new(params[:room])
    if @room.save
      flash[:notice] = "Room has been created!"
      flash[:color] = "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Room has not been created!"
      flash[:color] = "invalid"
    end
    render new
  end
end
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.  Thanks ahead of time.

EDIT:  When I run it on localhost it says:  undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Does it work on your own machine?

Comment: I was having trouble with running on localhost earlier and forgot I fixed that.  Got in a bad habit of pushing everything to heroku.  I edited my post on what it says when I run on localhost.  Seems to think @room is nil.

I am not sure 100% why it worked in the tutorial I followed but not in this...

Comment: Well, @room is probably nil. Which action do you call? Besides, you shouldn't use the same view for different actions.

Comment: Oh got it.  I was in index.html.erb, need to switch to new.html.erb.  Thank you.